# Hackerrank- Count Triplets C++ failing test case #10 & #11

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

Below is the C++ solution for the Count Triplets problem from the Hackerrank website. Problem link is given below:

[Count Triplets](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem)

[image]

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    long r;
    cin>>n>>r;
    long arr2[100006];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long a;
        cin>>a;
        arr2[i]=a;
    }
    long sum = 0;
    unordered_map<double, long> lfreq;
    unordered_map<double, long> rfreq;
    lfreq[arr2[0]]++;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
        rfreq[arr2[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++){
        long ans1=0, ans2=0;
        double prev=0;
        if(arr2[i]%r==0) prev= arr2[i]/r;
        double nxt = arr2[i]*r;
        //ans1 = count(arr2,arr2+i,prev);
        //ans2 = count(arr2+i+1,arr2+n,nxt);
        ans1 = lfreq[prev];
        ans2 = rfreq[nxt];
        lfreq[arr2[i]]++;
        if(rfreq[arr2[i]]>0) rfreq[arr2[i]]--;
        //cout<<arr2[i]<<"--->"<<ans1<<"--->"<<ans2<<endl; 
        sum += (ans1*ans2);
    }
    cout<<sum<<"\n";
}
```

The above code is failing for test case #10 & #11. What is not handled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `log(a/a0)` is not correct. You'll get integer division. Do `log(double(a)/a0)`

Comment: `cnt*cnt1` may cause overflow. Try `(long)cnt*cnt1`.

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do and provide expected and actual inputs and outputs without using links to external sites

Comment: Your code printed `0` for input `4 1 1 1 1 1` while `4` should be printed if my understanding is correct.

Comment: "_Problem link is given below_" -  Include the actual problem/question _in_ your question. Make your question self-contained.

Comment: @MikeCAT: yes your understanding is correct. I have added the right version of the code now.

Comment: The hackerrank test sets are all about *corner-cases*. Make sure you example the limits of the constraints given and there are usually a couple more cases that really take thinking to identify.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
    /**
     * This method assumes input is valid!
     * @param arr an ascending sorted list of factors of n
     * @param n the factor
     * @return a count of triplets
     */
    public int countTriplets(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        Map<Long, Long> cnt = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Long, Long> tots = new HashMap<>();
        long count = 0;
        for (long a : arr)
        {
            // Do only if a is divisible by r
            if (a % r == 0)
            {
                long n = a / r;
                count += tots.getOrDefault(n, 0L);
                tots.put(a, tots.getOrDefault(a, 0L) + cnt.getOrDefault(n, 0L));
            }

            // Increment count of a.
            cnt.put(a, cnt.getOrDefault(a, 0L) + 1);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

This is a single pass O(n) solution.
The base premise is this:
An element can "see" the count of values that are less than itself and have occurred before it.  So, as you read the elements, track how many can currently be seen, and how many have been seen.
The count is an aggregate of all these numbers.

--- Edit: Modified after running in Hackerrank.

Comment: this wouldd not work because the indices have to fullfil i < j < k. So for the input [2, 2, 4, 1] the correct output is 0 but your algorithm does not differentiate between this input and the one you have

Comment: Please refer to the original question posted - Sample Input 0 and Sample Output 0.  1, 2, 2, 4 the correct output is 2.

Comment: the input that I mentioned is not same as the sample input 0

Comment: As mentioned, I assumed input will always be in ascending order, as all sample in the question are in ascending order.  There is no indication that input will not be in ascending order.  For the input 2, 2, 4, 1, my code will output 0, but this is entirely accidental, as it will count 0, 2, 2, 0; and 0x2x2 = 0 + 2x2x0 = 0; and hence 0.

Comment: No, this is not how it works with competitive programming. you can never make an assumption that is not given in the problem. The input will not be in ascending order because in the question it is not mentioned that it will be. if in deed it is in ascending order, then the question is very badly formulated.

Comment: That's a difference in our reading of the question.  Anyhow, my code can be adjusted to easily cater for non-ascending order without affecting algorithm complexity (which is currently O(m+n), but the code will just become a bit messier.  I will post an alternate answer below just for you.

Comment: This is not a matter of reading. You are making an assumption which is not given in the question. Before you post it, could you maybe submit your code to the hackerrank actually? If it passes then we know that you are right.

Comment: @berkayberabi: You are correct, if it is not mentioned in the questions we can't assume it.

Comment: @John: It will be so nice of you, if you can test the same in hackerrank itself.

Comment: From this post, I am actually in which corner cases my solution posted above is not working. It is failing only two test cases out of 13.

Comment: I have run it in hackerrank now, and I understand the question more fully.  I have made slight modifications, and it is failing 2 tests only.  For the non-ordered scenario, I am trying to think of an efficient means of splitting the array into a set of ascending sub-arrays, and adding the results of the sub-arrays together.  Performing the split and conquer will fix the algo for the 2 remaining TCs.

Comment: OK, I bought some TCs in Hackerrank to see what numbers we were dealing with and have found the following: not all numbers are actually factors of r.  For instance, you can get r = 4, a = 3 12 48 => 1 hit.  This failed in my previous code as I had assumed all numbers to be perfect factors of r (r, r square, r cube, etc).  I have adjusted my code to handle non-factors AND to handle non-ordered.